# Capturing the equivalent of 'this' in a lambda in a static function

Tags: c++, c++11, static, lambda

I have a class looks like this:

```
class MyClass {
    static Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11VertexShader> vertexShader;
    static void Setup(Device* device) {
        auto createVSTask = loadVSTask.then([this, device]() {
            DX::ThrowIfFailed(
                device->CreateVertexShader(&vertexShader));
    }
}
```

I can't use `this` in the lambda because the function is static. What should I use instead?

Comment: @Barry It's just some parameter I forgot to include into the code.

Comment: Why do you think you need to capture a `this`-alike?  `static` variables and global variables can be accessed directly from lambdas, even stateless lambdas.

Comment: @BenVoigt I may be mistaking an error for something else then. What happened was that `vertexShader` ended up null, despite me just having copied the code from a non-static context. If it's supposed to work though then I'll look into it further, thanks.

Comment: @idlackage: It looks like you're using a task library here... maybe the smart pointer holds `null` because task hasn't run to completion yet and `CreateVertexShader` hasn't actually been called... That is, if you even started running the task in the first place.

Comment: In the end it does look like I've just completely forgot how static variables and async tasks work and confused myself. The error I'm getting is apparently irrelevant. Thanks to everyone for reminding me. (And yes that is the code that initializes `VertexShader`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a `this` pointer to access static methods or variables. Simply remove `this` from your capture list and the code will work.

```
static void Setup(Device* device) {
        auto createVSTask = loadVSTask.then([device]() {
            DX::ThrowIfFailed(
                device->CreateVertexShader(&vertexShader));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to capture `this` in order to have access to `vertexShader`... it's already accessible. All you need is to capture `device`:

```
static void Setup(Device* device) {
    auto createVSTask = loadVSTask.then([device]{
        DX::ThrowIfFailed(device->CreateVertexShader(&vertexShader));
    });
}
```